# Системные требования к веб хостингу (под приложение)

Tags: документация, стандарт, хостинг

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нибудь существует формализованный список вопросов на которые должен ответить разработчик, чтобы составить список системных требований под хостинг многопользовательского веб приложения? На данный момент мы имеем вот такой список:

```
 * База приложения: 
  * Вычислительная мощность,(cpu/ram/net) в пересчете на пользователей в день. 
  * Операционная система, род, мин версия, требуемые отклонения от стандартных настроек, предусмотренных поставщиком ОС, 
 * База данных: 
  * Вычислительная мощность,(cpu/ram/net) в пересчете на пользователей в день. 
  * Род БД описание реализации схемы репликации(если применимо) 
 * Резервное копирование. 
  * Примерный прирост, необходимо-достаточный для установки из резервной копии в течении одного дня, объема резервного дискового пространства в месяц. 
 * Сеть, 
  * Ширина канала к комплексу, требуемые значения входящего-исходящего суммарного канала.
```

---

нет ли вместо него какого нибудь стандарта типа ISO или IEEE ?

Comment: каждый под свои нужды выбирает такие вещи.

Comment: ну вот как под свои нужды. Диалог примерно следующий:

заказчик:

- мы хотим знать какой хостинг использовать

исполнитль

- выразите свой вопрос точнее

з

- лист свверху

и
- так что надо то ?

з

- а что непонятно ?

и

- ....

Comment: Извиняюсь за возможно глупый ответ, но RFC описал даже протокол обмена пакетами голубиной почтой (шуточно правда). Я уже второй год не могу осилить даже тот минимум стандартов инструментов, которыми я пользуюсь, слишком много "букав". Наверное, у них есть всё. =)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не связан с явной проблемой по про программированию и ведет к дискуссиям.

Comment: "нет ли вместо него какого нибудь стандарта типа ISO или IEEE ?" Мне кажется вопрос в такой формулировке не ведет к дискуссиям.

Answer (score 1):

Мониторил множество проектов на разных хостах, (специально, прочитав этот вопрос) определил некоторые требования.

Среднее потребления ОЗУ на юзера для генерации одной страницы (php) выходит ~7864320 машинных слов(15Mb, поправьте если ошибся), в остальных в два раза меньше вроде.

Рассчитаем примерно за сколько тактов комп рассчитает ту хрень что выгружает в озушку, = для 64 архитектуры(64 бита,8 байт(16 маш.слов) за такт) считаем по одной операции на блок данных 7864320/16 = 491520 тактов.

Теперь считаем сколько герц надо одному юзеру на каждый клик(такты/время между кликами примерно сек.) =  491520 герц (опер/сек) = 491.52 килогерц =~ 0.5 мегагерц. (опять таки поправьте если ошибся при переводе)

Не похоже на правду. Округлим MHz до 0,25-0,05. Скажите где косяк в рассчетах =)

Канал равен суммарному весу веб- страницы. Страница весит по разному. Я наблюдал 5 метров в среднем. Соответсвенно канал =~ 5метров/время между кликами.

Итого = 15Mb RAM/0.15MHz/5Mb/s в день на юзера.
ОС = Лучше на ядре похожем на Linux/WinNT (только вот под виндой я ещё сервера настраивать нормально не научился)

Comment: @Rijen, спасибо, но мне нужна была формулировка вопроса а не ответ :) ответ 42 я уже знаю :) В смысле мне нужен был опросник, для разработчиков, лучшее что я нашел на данный момент это ГОСТ, но он слишком широк и для веб проекта не подходит.

Comment: Тогда я не понял вопроса.
Может "Какие вопросы разработчик должен задать заказчику, чтобы определить требования под хост?"

Comment: Какие вопросы должен задать заказчик разработчику, чтобы перевести проект в рабочий цикл. Причем формальный список.

Answer (score 0):

Системные требования могут выглядеть следующие образом:

1. Сервер баз данных: MySQL, версии х.х или выше
2. Интерпритатор: php, версии выше х.х или выше
3. Платформа: Unix
4. Веб сервер: Apache, версии х.х или выше
5. Почтовый сервер: Exim, версии х.х

ну т.е. всё что касается серверного ПО, для того чтобы приложение запустилось.
Предложите вариант аренды облачного сервера, где можно по мере нагрузки добавлять ресурсы, потом когда придёт понимание что это неоправданного дорого можно смело брать выделенный сервер с уже известной конфигурацией + запас небольшой или большой если бюджет позволяет.

Касательно серверного железа, объёмов памяти, процессора, жёсткого диска, здесь необходим запуск приложения на тестовом сервере и его стресс тестирование, в самом простом виде утилитой ApacheBench (AB) + xDebug для поиска узких мест.

Только под нагрузкой можно понять какие объёмы будут нужны. Нагрузка не растёт линейно. И говорить о том, что генерация страницы занимает 15 МБ оперативной памяти это верх некорректности, аналогично по процессору и сети.

Comment: вот например по второму пункту скажем требуется apc (или наоборот противопоказана) а так-же gd и прочее, как нужно спрашивать чтобы разработчик не забыл  ответить ?  

По нагрузочному тестированию и прочему все понятно, не растет линейно ? отлично - примерно как растет (там все равно сильно сложнее гиперболоида с различными коэффициентами на каждый параметр обычно не бывает)

Comment: Ну и вопрос планирования - например с таким ответом "в текущей реализации система может выдержать до 10000тыс активных пользователей, (с граффиком потребления ресурсов типа [такого](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3De%5E%28x%2F900%29) - обратите внимание что происходит после 11000, имеет смысл   вбухивать в железо, или на 5000 лучше задуматься о новой версии ?